# Composition of bubbles in glass products

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy

I have noticed that some glass products hold small bubbles inside them:

[image]

Since the process by which these pieces are produced (forming) is unlikely to introduce air bubbles, I'm assuming that these bubbles are generated in the furnace as some of the elements or compounds in the glass come out of solution due to the high temperatures needed for glass production.

So, assuming that whatever gas that formed the bubble hasn't dissolved back into the the glass or escaped due to porosity. Is there a way to measure it's composition?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to trap air bubbles in glass products; the trick is how to minimize their occurrence in those applications where they would be objectionable.

There are microchemical techniques for determining the contents of a trapped gas bubble by cracking it open in the lab, which have been in use for years to for example analyze air bubbles in pieces of amber and thereby determine the composition of the atmosphere as it existed millions of years ago when the amber glob first formed.